# Unable to get the required key values with respect to different fields in python

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, scrapy

I am crawling through a series of APIs and trying to get the price from the keys. Some APIs have the value " AVG_price", "Average_price" and the rest have " price_min, price_max".

```
WANTED_PRICES = ['average_Price', 'average_price', 'avg_price', 'avg_Price']
WANTED_avgPRICES = ['price_min', 'price_max']
```

In order to get the prices, Average prices are required. So, the above two list of fields are treated differently.

If an api has "price_min" and price_max", the prices are calculated as the average of the two. And if the api has any field from "Wanted_Prices", then the price is just extracted as it is.

```
     def parse_slugs(self, response, slug_id, crawled_url):
        summary = json.loads(response.body)
        results = summary.get('results', [])
        for result in results:
            for result_avg, result_mm in zip(WANTED_PRICES, WANTED_avgPRICES):
                price = None
               if result_avg in result:
                    price = Decimal(result[result_avg])
                   
                elif result_mm in result:
                    minp = result['price_min']
                    maxp = result['price_max']
                    price = ((Decimal(minp + maxp)) / 2)
                if 'published_date' in result.keys():
                    date = result['published_date'].split(' ')[0]
                else:
                    date = result['published_Date'].split(' ')[0]

                print(slug_id,date,price)
```

But I am getting errors:

1. The prices from the  APIs that have the fields from "WANTED_avgPRICES" are not getting extracted. Only the date and the Slug_Id is shown in the output(for example):

```
{'1234'} 08/25/2020 None
{'1234'} 08/25/2020 None
{'1234'} 08/25/2020 None
{'1234'} 08/25/2020 None
```

2. It's giving out two outputs for each unique values.Duplicates

```
{'1053'} 07/01/2020 0.9137499999999999511501869165
{'1053'} 07/01/2020 0.9137499999999999511501869165
{'1053'} 06/25/2020 0.9137499999999999511501869165
{'1053'} 06/25/2020 0.9137499999999999511501869165
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, zip() stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted. It will ignore the remaining items in the longer iterables, cutting off the result to the length of the shortest iterable:

```
>>> list(zip(range(3), ['fee', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum']))
[(0, 'fee'), (1, 'fi'), (2, 'fo')]
```

This mean that you don't process ALL items from `WANTED_PRICES` list.